# what's the alternative to nested classes in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, nested-class

I read a post stating that 'nested classes wasn't pythonic' what's the alternative

please forgive me, this isn't the best example but it's the basic concept.  a nested class for performing a task.  I'm basically having to connect to a service in multiple threads.

```
import threading, imporedlib

class Mother(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self,val1,val2):
        self.VAL1 = val1
        self.VAL2 = val2
    def connectandrun():
        for i in range(5):
            Child.run(i)
    class Child:
        def run(self):
            importedlib.runajob(Mother.VAL1, Mother.VAL2)
```

Comment: What is the result that you're expecting from the code that you've written?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want to use composition:

```
import threading, importedlib

class Child:
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.parent=parent

    def run(self):
        importedlib.runajob(parent.VAL1, parent.VAL2)



class Mother(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self,val1,val2):
        self.VAL1 = val1
        self.VAL2 = val2

    def connectandrun():
        c= Child(self)
        for i in range(5):
            c.run(i)
```

Of course the names "Mother" and "Child" are not really appropriate anymore here, but you get the idea.